# How can I unlock Dwemer doors?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Throughout Skyrim, there are tower-like structures with four fenced gates inside: in the middle of them, there are four gears and a level.

I couldn't figure out how to open these doors: what do I need to do to open them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They cannot be opened from the outside. They can be opened by accessing them from below - specifically from Blackreach. You can get there via Alftand Glacial Ruins, and will need to do so for a portion of the main quest.

Comment: Thanks, then I will wait until the main quest take me there.