# How do I open the door to Alftand Cathedral?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do I open the door to Alftand Cathedral? I have tried a couple of times, and it seems that I can't open it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I unlock Dwemer doors?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37710/how-can-i-unlock-dwemer-doors)

Answer (score 4):

You can do i by doing [Discerning the Transmundane](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Discerning_the_Transmundane), or the main quest story line [Elder Knowledge](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Elder_Knowledge)

Answer (score 2):

It is part of a quest, you will have the opportunity to open the door once you start the related quest (one of the main storyline's quests).